# The universe doesn't have an end?

Tags: universe

So, I wanna understand more about the theory of what if the universe and all things have been always there and will always exist, existed before, now and after us, why do so little people can conceive this theory? it is palpable but does it sounds uncomfortable for most or really impossible?

Comment: See [Spinoza's God or Nature](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spinoza/#GodNatu)

Answer (score 2):

There was a 'steady state' theory pop the universe. One of the main proponents of this was Fred Hoyle, who coined the term 'Big Bang' to rubbish the opposing theory. The Steady State theory is a logical extension of the Copernican idea that we are not in a special place in the universe: we are also not in a special time. The universe goes on cooling and expanding forever, but new, low entropy matter pops into being everywhere to keep this process going. The expansion stops all the matter clumping together under gravity at larger and larger scales. It's like we are endlessly zooming into a fractal image.

It is a pretty idea, but it does not fit what we see. Deep space is very empty. We can see almost all the way back to the Big Bang. Any steady background creation of matter would create a fog at the very large distances. Instead, we can see clearly a long way, and see the galaxies have been swept into giant string structures which should not happen under a steady state. These days we can do giant computer simulations using our best guesses of cosmological constants such as the fraction of dark matter, and we get a realistic fit to what we see. This does not necessarily mean we are right, because the computer models tend to come up with 'swirly things' that look like spiral galaxies anyway, and we are just picking the one we think looks most like us. But it is a start.

The best extrapolation based on these models is that the universe will expand and cool forever. Eventually each particle will be separate for all other particles, as they can break up or evaporate (even if they are a black hole) much faster than they can recombine in the new, empty universe. It might seem neater and less 'wasteful' if the universe went back into a single point, and everything went back where it came from, but it is pretty clear it is not going to do that without something dramatic and new.

As with all science, this is work in progress. Dark matter was postulated since the 1930s. Dark energy is a lot newer, and there is talk of the 'Big Rip'. More and bigger telescopes may provide an answer.

To answer to the closing question: it is not that people cannot conceive of the steady state theory - in fact Steady State was thought of before the Big Bang, and it does have a certain 'neatness' - but it does not fit what we see in the sky.